# 1 to many mapping with conditions in SAS

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have 1 dataset set and want to match to itself, just to get fuzzy matching.

```
Age2    Gender4 Consonants2 Name_of_Patient_nospace2    SoundEx
5   F   h   Ahoi    A0
31  M   h   Ahoi    A0
35  F   y   AYEE    A0
33  F   y   AAYEE   A0
39  F   y   AYEE    A0
32  F   y   Ayai    A0
35  M   r   Aro A090
35  M   r   ARAAO   A090
33  M   r   ARao    A090
30  M   r   Arei    A090
35  M   r   Aro A090
35  M   r   ARAAO   A090
33  M   r   ARao    A090
30  M   r   Arei    A090
65  M   r   AARI    A090
```

Ran below code in SAS got n to n mapping (ABC and DEF table is same):

```
Proc Sql noprint;
Create table as Match
Select * from ABC as x inner join DEF as y
on (x.SoundEx = y.SoundEx_Copy) and (x.Consonants = y.Consonants_Copy)
where (x.Gender = y.Gender_Copy) and (x.Age2 - y.Age2_Copy) between -5 and 
5;
quit;
```

Can same code be executable in DATA step to get 1 to n mapping?
Eg: if we have 2 table both have 1,2,3 records then out should be as below (as per 1 to n mapping)

```
1-1
1-2
1-3
2-2
2-3
3-3
```

Comment: Your question is confusing. You have shown input, please let us know what the output should be

Comment: End result should be 1 to n fuzzy match basis name.
However to ease the process I ran Sound Expression function by which i got SoundEX code on names which pronounce similar.
So, if following condition matches then join:
1. Soundex and consonants should be same
2. Gender should be same
3. Join data if age is +-5 (if 1 row has age 10 then the matching row should have age b/w 5 to 15)

ABC and DEF table have same above data, but DEF table has suffix "_Copy" in Column names.

Comment: It sounds like you're doing probabilistic matching, have you tried PROC PSMATCH, available in the latest release.

Comment: If SQL is working why do you want to do the same in data step ?  I would recommend putting an identifier in your initial data set and do not copy to a second data set.  Learn about aliases in SQL. `select ONE.id as id1, TWO.id as id2, ... from myTable as ONE cross join myTable as TWO where ... matching conditions ... and ONE.id ne TWO.id`

Comment: I think the logic you're looking for is: `where (x.Gender = y.Gender_copy) 
having abs(x.Age2 - y.Age2_copy)<5;`